# Как передать изображение из Django rest framework в react

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-rest-framework

Я делаю интернет-магазин используя drf + react. Как мне передать изображение из drf на react. Все сделал вроде как полагается. В settings media root и media url определены. Изображение храниться нормально. На клиент я передаю url изображения и когда ставлю его в src тега img изображение не появляется. Как это правильно реализовать. Помогите пожалуйста.